# Why does one of these semingly equivalent macros fail?

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

Consider these two macro definitions:

```
macro createTest1()
    quote
        function test(a = false)
            a
        end
    end |> esc
end

macro createTest2()
    args = :(a = false)
    quote
        function test($args)
            a
        end
    end |> esc
end
```

According to the builtin Julia facilities they should both evaluate to the same thing when expanded:

```
println(@macroexpand @createTest1)
begin
    function test(a=false)
        a
    end
end
println(@macroexpand @createTest2)
begin
    function test(a = false)
        a
    end
end
```

Still I get a parse error when trying to evaluate the second macro:

```
@createTest2
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "a = false" is not a valid function argument name
```

It is a space in the second argument list. However, that should be correct Julia syntax. My guess is that it interprets the second argument list as another Julia construct compared to the first. If that is the case how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the second macro is failing as stated in my question above. It looks correct when printed however args is not defined correctly and Julia interprets it as an expression which is not allowed. The solution is to instead define args according to the rules for function parameters. The following code executes as expected:

```
  macro createTest2()
    args = Expr(:kw, :x, false)
    quote
        function test($(args))
            a
        end
    end |> esc
  end
```